# Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn not loading

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, installshield-le

I have created a solution with a Outlook AddIn Project and a InstallShield LE Setup Project. I followed this Walkthrough to create the Setup Project:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)

I installed my AddIn on a user-level. Here are some screenshots from my Setup Project:

[image]

Here I added the project output by going to "Add Project Output" and then selecting "Primary  Output" from the list and clicking OK.

[image]

[image]

Here I added the registry keys for a user-level installation. I am not sure if what I did here is correct and I suspect that the error lies here. I have tried following the walkthrough but I am not sure if I added the keys for the AddIn and it's FormRegion correctly (The AddIn has exactly one FormRegion).

I added the FormRegion Manifest File according to this Walkthrough:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942741%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Does anybody know what could be wrong here? I don't get any error messages and the AddIn shows in the COM-AddIn dialog in Outlook 2010 but after checking it, it doesn't load. After going into the COM-Addin dialog again, it has unchecked itself. I have also checked the disabled items, however, the AddIn does not appear here.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem. For some reason, the way I added the registry key for the FormRegion was not correct. The correct way is to add the Key with the corresponding class name, in my case `IPM.Appointment`. Then I had to add a string value with the **full** name, in my case `Condato.Terminauswertung.CustomPropertiesFormRegion` and the name of the Add-In with a preceding equal sign as value, in my case `=Condato.Terminauswertung`. You can find the first two values in the FormRegion class file near the top.